# Command-line tool to substitute environment variables

Tags: bash, environment-variables, sh, substitution

I am interested if there is a UNIX tool which replaces occurences of `$VAR` or `${VAR}` (for all existing variables in the env, not just one) with the actual values of environment variables. This replacment is in a plain text file, not a bash script; a "poor man's template engine" of sort.

I know I can do

`(echo 'echo -n "'; sed -e "s/\"/\"'\"'\"/g" infile; echo '"') | sh -s >outfile`

(I do, in fact), but if there is a well-known tool for that, I'd rather use it instead of clever `sh` tricks.

EDIT: @glennjackman suggest use of `eval`, so the line is shorter and without subshell:

`` eval echo -n \""`sed -e 's/"/\\\\\\\"/g' infile`"\" >outfile ``

which is pretty short (though not a dedicated tool, but good enough if there is none).

Comment: I have not tried this (hence the comment), but with a simple script it should be possible to use `bash -x infile 2> outfile`, which will do all shell expansions.

Comment: @cdarke: I did not know `bash -x`, but I wonder if it would work in generic replacement in a text file, not in a bash script...

Comment: @glennjackman: `eval` may help me in fact with the trick above to ditch subsscript (thus, no need to `export`), thanks. But alone, it would try to evaluate the contents, which is not a script, but a normal text file. What I look for is "poor man's template engine". :-)

Comment: @glennjackman Maybe make your suggestion an answer, I will pick if nothing shorter appears.

Comment: @herby:  no, it would not be generic.  It will also depend exactly what type of shell expansions on variables you need to support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example with `eval`

```
tmpl='Hello $x'
x=world
eval str=\"$tmpl\"
echo $str   # => Hello world
```

If your template has embedded double quotes, this will get messy.

Comment: I already solved the embedded double quotes in the EDIT part, but it needed 7 backslashes :-)